# pgsql how to count values from two columns

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables

First Table:

```
num  |  job1  | job2
--------------------
 1       14      12 
 2       23      14
 3       3       12
 4       21      3
 5       6       8
```

second:

```
id  |  jobs
------------
3   
12
14
21
23
etc...
```

I need to count how many times `second table's id` appears at `first table,s
columns job1 and job2` and update that total value to `second table column "jobs"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a correlated update.

```
UPDATE table2 t2
SET    jobs = (SELECT Count(*) AS job_count
               FROM   (SELECT job1 id
                       FROM   table1
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT job2 id
                       FROM   table1) t1
               WHERE  t1.id = t2.id
               GROUP  BY id);
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2f448d/1)

Answer (score 2):

You need to first un-pivot the first table, so that you can group on the job ids:

```
select t.job_id, count(*) as num_jobs
from first_table, unnest(array[job1, job2]) as t(job_id)
group by t.job_id;
```

With your sample data that returns:

```
job_id | num_jobs
-------+---------
    21 |        1
     6 |        1
    12 |        2
    23 |        1
    14 |        2
     3 |        2
     8 |        1
```

Now this can be used to update the second_table:

```
update second_table 
  set jobs = x.num_jobs
from (
  select t.job_id, count(*) as num_jobs
  from first_table, unnest(array[job1, job2]) as t(job_id)
  group by t.job_id
) x 
where x.job_id = id;
```

Answer (score 0):

And yet another solution:

```
update table2 set
  jobs = (
    select sum(case when job1 = job2 then 2 else 1 end)
    from table1
    where table2.id = job1 or table2.id = job2)
```